# stauffer grimson background subtraction in opencv

Tags: opencv

I have heard that there is a function to do stauffer grimson background subtraction in opencv .
I don't know - which function to use and what input it requires ?

I am guessing it will need 
(1)k (number of gaussian associated with each pixel) 
(2)threshold (if gaussians of pixel are arranged in descending order of their height then the summation of first few < threshold are classified as background , rest as foreground)
NOTE:summation of heights of all gaussians for a pixel will be always one.
(3)Learning parameter alpha for weight of gaussian and rho for updating position and variance of gaussian

Now the practical details

I have an mpg video (352x240 resolution). I decomposed it into png (3 channel) frames (30 per second)
All png frames kept in 'trial' folder
I compile the code given below using
 g++ mycode.c -o mybinary  -I /usr/include/opencv2/imgproc/   `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv`

Currently - This is my code

```
#include"cv.h"
#include"highgui.h"
#include"imgproc.hpp"
using namespace cv;
#define ROW 240
#define COLUMN 352

int main(void)
{   Mat color_image,gray_image;
    char imgfile[100];
    int filecount=1;
    for(filecount=1;filecount<901;filecount++)
    {   sprintf(strimgfile,"trial/image-%d.png",filecount);
        image = imread(strimgfile,1);
        cvtColor(color_image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY );
        // now I can pass the color_image or gray_image to
        // stauffer grimson algorithm for procesing
        // don't know - how to proceed ?
    }
```

Thanks.

source:http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/vsam/Publications/stauffer_cvpr98_track.pdf

PS: I am using opencv on 64 bit ubuntu 14.04 .

Comment: [These](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/df6/classcv_1_1BackgroundSubtractor.html) are the different flavors of background subraction implemented in OpenCV. I think none of them is taken from your paper, but the MOG or MOG2 variants should be quite close

Comment: will try http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html